# In a directive is it possible to target a variable on the scope using a string value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a directive and I need to set a variable on the scope, but all I have to work with is a string value that describes the path of the var:

```
var toChange = "targetObj['targetProp']";
```

I asked a question long ago regarding finding nested properties within a known object (and got a working answer), but haven't been successful leveraging that to look on the scope...is there a way to basically take that path and find it on the scope? This doesn't work but something along the lines of:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> scope.toChange = newValue;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `$scope.$eval`:

```
var toChange = "targetObj['targetProp']";

var target = $scope.$eval(toChange);

target = newVal;
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $scope/$rootScope API Reference - $eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Comment: Sweet - thanks for the tip, that's gonna come in handy :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured it out, sorry everyone!

```
var x = $parse(toChange);
x.assign(scope, newVal);
```